# How to use default item in actionbarsherlock?

Tags: java, android

In my android application I use `actionbarsherlock`, I set the action bar as theme in my manifest file android: `theme = "@ style / Theme.Sherlock.Light"` and I want to click on the logo placed on the default bar,
but how can I do it?

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Please take some time to improve your question. See that you use proper formatting and explain properly what your problem is. "I can't" isn't proper problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();

mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);`